# Python Pandas Replace multiple values in one column with dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, multivalue

I have the below df as an example

| Product Code | Product Type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01478 | ELC | £119.00 |
| 01479 | GRN | £159.00 |
| 01514 | PWR | £100.00 |
| 01617 | ELC | £119.00 |
| 01819 | ELC - GRN - PWR | £300.00 |
| 01819 | ELC - GRN - PWR | £300.00 |

I am trying to change multiple values in the 'Product Type' column using a dict

This is my code:

```
df['Product Type'] = df['Product Type'].str.replace('ELC', 'Electric')
df['Product Type'] = df['Product Type'].str.replace('GRN', 'Green')
df['Product Type'] = df['Product Type'].str.replace('PWR', 'Power Supply')
```

When I use this it changes the values and works, even for ELC - GRN - PWR

However when I try to use a dict method just to improve code readability and make it more simple instead of loads of str.replace lines.

```
dict = {
    'ELC' : 'Electric', 
    'GRN' : 'Green', 
    'PWR': 'Power Supply', 
    '-' : ' '}
```

It only changes the single ELC to Electric, and GRN to Green but does not change the ELC - GRN - PWR to Electric - Green - Power Supply.

Can I ask why this happens and what the solution is?

I've looked at many different approaches in stack but nothing seems to work effectively.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `regex` inside `df.Series.replace` (without `str`):

```
df['Product Type'] = df['Product Type'].replace(dict, regex=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't replace anything, I tried this with the dict and it runs without an error but the dataframe remains the same?

Comment: You need to assign this to a column. I've updated the answer

Comment: Haha Cheers, I just tried this too and it works great! Thank You :)